# Get page ratings with Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hope you can help.  I'm working on a website for a client and they want the Reviews tab of their Facebook page to feed directly to their website in a Testimonials section.  I have read the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/) and followed these steps:

1. I've been added as Admin on their page
2. I've obtained their Page ID
3. I've checked that there are in fact reviews on their page
4. I've setup a new Facebook App and received an AppID and Secret
5. I've used the Facebook Graph API explorer to obtain a page access token for their page (short-lived)

However, when I run `{page-id}/ratings` in the Graph API Explorer (or on a website) I get no data:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
}
```

I have tried this with the `open_graph_story` field and other fields and get the same result.

Any advice on how I can troubleshoot this would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ and we'll take a look. Make sure to include as much detail as possible: your App ID, your URLs, the access tokens you're using, etc.